# Android Shared preferences with multiple activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

1. How do I retrieve  shared preferences that have been saved from a
   previous activity?
2. Do I need to enable file writing or some other manifest modifications?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You don't need any special manifest modificaiton to achieve that.

Assuming you have already saved preferences you can read those preferences at anytime doing something like I show bellow.

1. Write on Shared Preferences file:

   > ```
   >   SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("your_file_name", MODE_PRIVATE);
   >   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
   >   editor.putString("yourStringName", "this_is_the_saved_value");
   >   editor.commit(); // This line is IMPORTANT. If you miss this one its not gonna work!
   > ```
2. Read from Shared Preferences file:

   > ```
   >   SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("your_file_name",
   >   MODE_PRIVATE); String string = prefs.getString("yourStringName",
   >   "default_value_here_if_string_is_missing");
   > ```

You can use a default file to save/ read your preferences. Just replace the first line of the two code snippets above by something like: `SharedPreferences prefs = getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());`

Thats it! Check the Android Developers dedicated page to this matter, [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

Hope it was usefull. Let me know about it.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to do anything special, other than make sure both activities are writing to/reading from the same file. Under the hood, preferences are just stored as an XML file.

So, your choices are:

1) Use [PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences%28android.content.Context%29) from both activities to write to the default file.

2) Use [Context.getSharedPreferences()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) specifying a custom file name, and use the same name from both activities.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me, also between sending intents and preferences, which is better used to pass around variables which store short strings?

Comment: It depends on how many variables you want to pass, and if you want them to be permanent. If you have more than 20 permanent variables to pass around, I'd consider a sqlite database. If you are just passing around few variables between activities, using intents is the better choice if you dont mind the variables get cleared once you exit the application.

Answer (score 2):

Shared Preferences are just that, shared. As long as you properly save the preferences after editting them by calling Editor.commit(), they will be available in the future.