# Skip start of Activity if a condition has already been met

Tags: android

In my Android app i have a Google plus login activity with the method

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    String accountName = mPlusClient.getAccountName();
    Toast.makeText(this, accountName + " is connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    ...
    Intent userDetailsCaptureIntent = new Intent(this,UserDetailsCaptureActivity.class);
    startActivity(userDetailsCaptureIntent);
}
```

In this method after the user has been signed in, i start the `UserDetailsCaptureActivity` where details about the user are collected and stored in a Google App Engine backend.The problem is after i enter the details and save them i don't want Activity to ever start again, but it starts because i keep calling it the `onConnected()` method. How do i let the Activity with the onConnected method know that `UserDetailsCaptureActivity` should only be called once? If this is confusing am willing to explain further.

Comment: Use shared preference to check the login status, but make sure that you are saving this details on login success.

Comment: could you explain further please.I have no problems with login status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save these user data in [SharedPreference](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/) when user fills up them in UserDetailsCaptureActivity.java.

```
userDetailsPrefEditor.putString("user_name", userName).commit();
```

Then after each successsful login, you need to check if the data already exists in SharedPreference or not.

```
userName = userDetailsPrefEditor.getString("user_name", "default");

if (userName == "default")
{
    //start activity for capturing details
}
else
{
    //do something else
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: let me clarify my question.I have no problem getting the data.When i enter the user data into my textfields and press submit it is entered into my Google App Engine backend as expected.Now when the user of my app launches my app again, i want the app to "know" that the data containing user details has already been captured therefore ignoring the start of `UserDetailsCaptureActivity` and proceeding to another activity.

Comment: It is clear to me. Read answer again. @OjonugwaOchalifu First time, it will not get Captured user details in shared preference and it will start activity. In that activity, you will save data in shared preference (not all data, just a boolean that user has filled form.) And whenever user starts the app again, on login, shared pref will give data and that activity won't be started.

Comment: So you want the UserDetailsCaptureActivity to open only once when the user details are not already filled in ?

Comment: seems like that. @San E.g. setting kind of thing

Comment: @Mystic Magic,Then your answer would work like a charm.

Comment: oh i see.I thought that was what you meant but was confused by your use of `username`.This would mean i need to delete the intent to start `UserDetailsCaptureActivity` in `onConnected` and then add the code to check the boolean there right?

Comment: @Ojonugwa Ochalifu, You gotta receive the data from UserDetailsCaptureActivity in your onConnected and check whether it already exists in the shared preference. If this is not what you're looking for then ask for more. I'll try my best.

Comment: @OjonugwaOchalifu yes. right :) intentb will go in if condition, where userdata is not found in shared preferences.

Comment: You cannot delete the intent, it needs to be there for the first time info filling.

Comment: Lol.That is True @San

Comment: @MysticMagic One last question, how do i get userDetailsPrefEditor in my LoginActivity since it is declared in the UserDetailsCaptureActivity? I tried to declare sharedPreferences as static but it won't work.

Comment: @OjonugwaOchalifu Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12433138) answer to check an example of shared preference across multiple activities. :)

Answer (score 0):

Following @MysticMaggic's answer, i finally got it to work.For future reference, this is what i did:

In the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method of my `UserDetailsCaptureActivity.java` class (where i want to save the sharedPreferences) i did

```
SharedPreferences userDetailsPrefEditor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
    final Editor editor = userDetailsPrefEditor.edit();


    final Intent userProfileDisplayIntent = new Intent(this, UserProfileActivity.class);

    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(v.getId() == R.id.userDetailsCaptureButton) {
                new EndpointsTask().execute(getApplicationContext());
                editor.putBoolean("hasSetDetails", true);
                editor.commit();
                startActivity(userProfileDisplayIntent);

            }
            }
        });
```

and then in the `onConnected()` method of my `LoginActivity` (where i want to access the sharedPreferences and check if the user has already entered their details) i did this

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    ...
    SharedPreferences userDetailsPrefEditor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
    boolean hasSetDetails = userDetailsPrefEditor.getBoolean("hasSetDetails", false);
    ...

  if (hasSetDetails == true) { //If user has already entered their details show profile page, else show user details capture screen.
       Intent userProfileDisplayIntent = new Intent(this, UserProfileActivity.class);
       startActivity(userProfileDisplayIntent);
   } else {
       Intent userDetailsCaptureIntent = new Intent(this, UserDetailsCaptureActivity.class);
       startActivity(userDetailsCaptureIntent);
    }
}
```

That's all.