# How to check if current user is logged in android

Tags: android

How to check if current user is logged in android.
I have an external database, I have successfully connected it to the database.
I need to check if the user is logged in or not

if user not logged will display {register activity} otherwise will display {my info activity}

Comment: You can use shared preference for that. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21703572/1777090) answer.

Comment: how you connected to your database ?

Comment: with json and php....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin):

To check if the user is signed-in, call isConnected().

```
if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
   // signed in. Show the "sign out" button and explanation.
   // ...
} else {
   // not signed in. Show the "sign in" button and explanation.
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Then, how to implement it inside a fragment?

Comment: Will it work if after login via Google user changes the password of his Gmail account (from Gmail website)

Answer (score 19):

It can be done by `sharedpreferences` and if you want to do from database then take one Boolean and save log in info according  to user id and then when you first time login then make it `true` and after that any time just fetch that Boolean and if true then  {my info activity} other wise {register activity}  simple is it dude :)

like this for using `sharedpreferences` when first time login then

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
prefs.edit().putBoolean("Islogin", Islogin).commit(); // islogin is a boolean value of your login status
```

and anytime when u want to get status then

```
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        boolean Islogin = prefs.getBoolean("Islogin", false); // get value of last login status
```

Now check

```
if(Islogin)
        {   // condition true means user is already login
            Intent i = new Intent(this, "your login activity");
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
        }

else
{
    // condition false take it user on login form 
}
```

Comment: if token expired ? How do you know about ?

Comment: For token validation you do need to make web server call to check.

Answer (score 0):

Save the state in PreferenceManager.

You can see a little example [here](https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/63/example_preferences_in_android)

Comment: The link works, but you get a https error because the web has 7 years...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to test if the user is logged in to the device, it is sufficient to do this with `SharedPreference` as others indicated.

However, if you want to ensure that the user is logged in to your external website, it is more complicated and requires more work.

1- Your website should have *remember me* functionality by setting some cookie

2- Once the user logged in successfully to your website from the app; you need to preserve the *remember me* cookie (e.g. serialize it to some file)

3- When the user open the app, you have to load that cookie if exists and make a request to the server to ensure if the user still logged in or not (e.g. handle the HTTP response code)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in two ways. One is storing them in a global variables and second is storing the data in shared preferences. see [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/) example.