# Checking if a user has already signed in with the google account with Kotlin results in null pointer exception

Tags: kotlin, google-authentication

I'm trying to check if the user is already signed in to google in kotlin.

```
fun isSignedIn(): Boolean {
        println(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser)
        println(GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
        return GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this) != null
    }
```

However I'm not sure why I'm getting the null pointer exception for the line `GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
```

I've been looking at other stackoverflow threads and following what has been suggested, but I'm not sure what the problem is.

1. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38190253/android-google-sign-in-check-if-user-is-signed-in#:~:text=To%20check%20if%20the%20user%20is%20signed-in%2C%20call%20isConnected,isConnected()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38190253/android-google-sign-in-check-if-user-is-signed-in#:%7E:text=To%20check%20if%20the%20user%20is%20signed-in%2C%20call%20isConnected,isConnected()).

Am I overlooking something very simple? Thank you.

Comment: What is `this`? What class is this function defined in?

Comment: I created a new class called "Authentication" and defined the function in this class. ```this``` is the application context

Comment: How can this be both a Context and your Authentication class?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why I'm getting the null pointer exception but if anyone else encounters the same problem, it seems:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser != null
```

works fine too.

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.displayName
```

gets the user name, where as

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
```

gets the uid